# How to use param value in body in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Currently i am working on post api and sending userid and password from param. but now i want to change the way and want to send username and password from body.

**Current code**

```
 const otpLoginAction: any = (formValues: { mobile: string }) => ({
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: `/user/auth/client/otp/send?mobile=${formValues.mobile}`,
      body: {},
    });

<TextField id="phoneNumber"
 name="phoneNumber"
label="Enter Mobile Number*"
className="form-input-custom"
value={values.phoneNumber}
onChange={handleNumberChange}
error={errors.phoneNumber}/>
```

**Requirement**

```
 const otpLoginAction: any = (formValues: { mobile: string }) => ({
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: `/user/auth/client/otp/send`,
      body: {
         mobile:'${formValues.mobile}'
      },
    });

<TextField id="phoneNumber"
 name="phoneNumber"
label="Enter Mobile Number*"
className="form-input-custom"
value={values.phoneNumber}
onChange={handleNumberChange}
error={errors.phoneNumber}/>
```

when i am using **mobile:'${formValues.mobile}'** value showing '${formValues.mobile}'

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you're using **single quotes('')** instead of **Backticks(``)** inside your mobile field.

Change it to this if you want to pass the mobile number as string.

```
mobile:`${formValues.mobile}`
```

If you want to pass it as a number then you don't need to use Backticks.

```
mobile: formValues.mobile
```